# Insert entire row beyond Table bounds using 'Table.ListRows.Add'

Tags: excel, vba

I have to insert a blank row in an Excel Table. To insert the row in the Table I am using:

```
bugetTable.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
```

So far so good, but the desired result is that the entire row needs to be shifted not just the row in the Table.  What I mean is, the Table range is four columns wide, so I need that the inserted row take more than the four columns. I am using the Table instead of the range row approach for technical requirements.

I am using Office 2010, Windows 8.1.

Comment: Not sure that I understand yet. You need to insert 4 or more columns?

Comment: No rohrl77, I need to expand the insertion of the row in the table, beyond the table boundaries, I mean, my table have a 4 columns range, I need to insert a row beyond that 4 columns, when you add a row in a table, using ListRows.Add it only insert a row in the whole table range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim b As Integer
Dim b As Integer
```

And, additional 3 steps:

Get the last row of the table:

```
a = ListObjects(YourTable).Range.Rows.Count
```

Get the row your table begins:

```
b = ListObjects(YourTable).Range.Cells(1).Row
```

Insert row by the end of the table:

```
Rows(a + b - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: Thanks Balinti I will give a try and let you know!

Comment: It´s work Balinti, Just had to change 

    ListObjects(TableName).Range.Rows.Count

To:

    ListObjects(TableName).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

The same for the line that get the first row of the Table.  Another thing is that if you use Rows(a + b - 1) this add the row in the row after the last one, I just omitted the -1 and everything is Ok.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might have to add a separate cell insert for the remaining columns if you have to use the table.  Assuming x is the current row you're at, which you may know.

```
Cells(x,5).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: Thank Liss, I will give a try too to this code too, and will let you know if this works.

Comment: Your solution works Liss, Thanks, but I use the one provided by Balitin, we are trying to avoid the Select methods. But again, thanks for taking time to  help me.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this?

```
Sub InsertRows()

With Sheet1
    .Range("1:4").EntireRow.Insert
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No rohrl77, as I said in the previous comment, it´s not a column insert, is a row insert. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Understand per your new comment above what you are asking for.